# Trying to Load HTML Source Code using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to load some HTML source code I have in a text file into jquery. When I click the link to add the text nothing loads into the page. Any suggestions?

 Load Script:

```
<div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="true">
    <h3>Accordion Concept</h3>
    <p>The accordion concept splits the page into catagories to save space. Each catagory contains information but this information is collapsed in order to make it so you only see the information you want to see on the page.</p>
    <div id = "loadEx">Click Here to Load Example Script File</div>
    <script>
        $( "#loadEx" ).click(function() {
            $('#hello').load('mywebpage.txt');
        });
    </script>
    <pre id = "hello"></pre>
</div>
```

Text File:

```
<body class="container">
    <div data-role="page">
        <div data-role="header">
            <h1> Page  One Title </h1>
        </div>
        <div data-role="content">
            <div data-role="collapsible-set" >
                <div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="true">
                    <h3> Header number one </h3>
                    <p> information for header number one is here. </p>
                </div>
                <div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="true">
                    <h3> Header number two </h3>
                    <p> information for header number two is here. </p>
                </div>
                <div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="true">
                    <h3> Header number three </h3>
                    <p> information for header number three is here. </p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div data-role="footer">
                Copyright
            </div>   
        </div>

</body>
```

Comment: What does the JavaScript error console say? What happens if you add `console.log` statements to the function? does the function run at all? What happens in the Net tab of the browser's developer tools? Is the HTTP request made? Is the response what you expect?

Comment: No error. It works if I write something like "hi". Just with the HTML it pretty much adds a blank div.

Comment: What happens if you examine the `<pre>` element with the DOM inspector? Do you see the HTML there? What styles are applied to it?

Comment: The physical HTML is added into the page when I look at the DOM inspector.

Comment: So it is being added to the page then. Now you just need to fix your CSS so it shows up.

Comment: Use Ajax call to render data like this. Make an ajax call to the text file and then get your desired result

Comment: @Ganesh — That's what the original code is already doing!

Comment: @Quentin what would I change in the CSS that would make it so it appears as text rather than HTML?

Comment: @AnikChaudhry — That's a different question entirely.

Comment: Your textfile contains a `<body class="container">` tag which your original site already has. Try to remove that. It is also not closed correctly. And your `<div>` elements are not balanced either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The real question emerged through the comments:

> what would I change in the CSS that would make it so it appears as text rather than HTML?

You wouldn't use CSS for that. You need to not use the `load` method (which is designed to handle HTML, not text).

Use a less short-handy Ajax function, and manually put the data into the element as text.

```
        $( "#loadEx" ).click(function() {
            $.get('mywebpage.txt', function (data) {
                $('#hello').text(data);
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

first load the dom then use $.get function.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $( "#loadEx" ).click(function() {

  $('#hello').html("hey there, I am calling get request");
  $.get('mywebpage.txt',function(data,status){
    if(status == "error"){
        alert("File not found "+status);
    }

    $('#hello').html(data);

  });

 });
```